# [[maybe_unused]] with structured_binding?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
: warning: unused variable ‘_y’ [-Wunused-variable]
[[maybe_unused]] const auto [x, _y] = f();
```

How do I prevent the warning here? `[[maybe_unused]]` doesn't seem to work in this case?

Comment: What compiler (and version)?

Comment: Neither Clang 5 nor GCC 9 produce such diagnostic.

Comment: Just upgrade compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/CYhWGq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by comments, `-Wunused-variable` only appears in gcc7

`[[maybe_unused]]` is not needed for newer gcc